# How to make a bootable disc in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, bootable-disk

Many searches and tutorials all showed that if you drop an `.iso` file in `Disc Utility` and go to `Burn` it will make a bootable disc but when I do it in Yosemite it will burn a copy of the `.iso` file.  How do I make a bootable disc in Yosemite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Locate the `.iso` file you want to burn and place it on your Desktop:

[image]

- Navigate to to `Disc Utility` (`Applications -> Utilities -> Disc Utility`)

[image]

- Once `Disc Utility` is opened, drag and drop the `.iso` file into the side panel and highlight the `.iso` file:

[image]

- Click `Convert` located at the top:

[image]

- Under `Convert` use the settings of `Where: Desktop`, `Image Format: DVD/CD master` and `Encryption: none` and choose `Save`:

[image]

- Drag and drop the `.cdr` file from your desktop into the side panel and select the `.cdr` file:

[image]

- Enter a new disc
- Click `Burn` located at the top and you should be prompted to burn the `.cdr` to the disc:

[image]

Comment: I ended up here trying to create a readable, much less bootable, Ubunto boot DVD-R from an iso. Your steps seem to be the same steps as described in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5132196), except you left off a very important note: `Depending on what OS built the .iso, the result may not be readable by your Mac...` So I was following your directions, but thinking they were still failing because the result wasn't readable, though it turned out the result did work as a boot DVD on my other system.

Comment: If there is a difference i will go back ans check but i posted this because all the research i couldn't figure out why it didnt work.  I still use this approach so if you are saying a particular ISO file isnt working let me know and ill test.

Answer (score 0):

If you've [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/) app installed, the easiest way is to right click on the `.iso` file and select '*Burn Disk Image XXX to Disc...*". This will run the app with appropriate settings. When ready, hit the *Burn* button.

Should work in *El Capitan* and *Sierra* macOS as well.